# What is the correct format to PHP echo a JavaScript Alert which uses PHP variables?

Tags: javascript, php, html, alert

I used

```
<?php     
$myArr =  "foo" => "bar",
          "bar" => "foo",; 
$myVar =  "Word!";

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The $myVar is print_r($myArr) ");</script>';
?>
```

To show an alert on the page. I take it is wrong, whats the right way of doing so?

Comment: it doesn't work bc thats not valid php

Comment: I suspect the real issue is the missing square brackets around the values of $myArr - see my edit to Paul's answer. That, and the fact that print_r() won't run inside that string.

Comment: I actually copy+paste'd the array from http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and didnt copy it all, only for demo here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always JSON-encode data used in the context of JavaScript.  This makes the data safe for use, so you don't have to worry about injection or escaping.

```
<script>
  <?php 
      $myArr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
      $myVar = 'Word!';
      echo 'var myArr = ', json_encode($myArr), ';'; // var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      echo 'var myVar = ', json_encode($myVar), ';'; // var myVar = "Word!";
  ?>

  console.log(myArr);
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the echoed `var` statements be inside the `<script>` tag?

Comment: All true - but for the sake of the OP, consider actually including the requested `alert()` instead of a normally-invisible `console.log()`

Comment: @PaulRoub I chose not to because it complicates things, since he wanted something equivalent to `print_r()`.  I didn't want to confuse him with stringifying it for display.  This way, he gets an example of an array and a string and learns how to properly debug all in one go.

Comment: But I cant just drop it in the PHP code. Will that be a good solution if I am to have multiple snippets like that?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul What do you mean?  You can put the code wherever you want/need.

Comment: The code I showed above was only meant to to be used as a general example. My actual PHP is full page with forms and etc. Should I encapsulate the entire PHP code with the `<script>` ?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul No, of course not.  You can open/close PHP tags as you need, or simply echo the `<script>` part out from within the PHP script.  What I prefer to do is have one associative array or object of stuff that I need to assign to JavaScript, and then json_encode and assign the whole thing.  This is easy to echo out in one place of your code.  You can also do this with a template engine, but that isn't strictly  required.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to `echo` the above code but I am getting error. Probably because of wrong `"` or `'` notation. What is the right way to `echo` it out?

Comment: `echo '<script>var x=', json_encode($x), ';</script>';`

Answer (score 0):

Like [sean9999's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23522488/3019302), this one avoids polluting the global namespace, but in a more straightforward way, without PHP short tags.

```
<?php $bar = "qux"; ?>

<script>
;(function () {
    var foo = <?php echo json_encode($bar); ?>;
    alert(foo);
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you might do it in a way that limits potential for polluting the global namespace

```
<?php
$myArr =  ["foo" => "bar", "bar" => "foo"]; 
$myVar =  "Word!";
?>
<script>
;(function(myArr,myVar){
  "use strict";
  alert( myVar + ' is ' + JSON.stringify(myArr) );
})(<?= json_encode($myArr) ?>,'<?= $myVar ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: Even though `$myVar` is a string, you must still escape it.  While that string contains "Word!" today, it certainly won't always.  Even if you did want to use it as a string, it's missing quotes.  `json_encode()` everything used in the context of JavaScript and you don't have to worry about this.